# Need help with starting a proof of linear independence

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\mathbb{R}^m$, $\mathbb{R}^n$ be Euclidean spaces. 
Let $T: \mathbb{R}^m → \mathbb{R}^n$ be a linear transformation with corresponding $n × m$ matrix A. 
Let $x_1, x_2, ..., x_k \in \mathbb{R}^m$ be vectors such that the set of vectors $\{T(x_1), T(x_2), ..., T(x_k)\}$ is linearly independent.

PROVE: 
The set $\{x_1, x_2, ..., x_k\}$ is linearly independent.

Comment: hint:write definitions and notice that T is linear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: If $\alpha_1 x_1+\cdots+\alpha_k x_k=0$, then $\alpha_1 T(x_1)+\cdots+\alpha_k T(x_k)=0$.

Solution: Assume that $T(x_1), \ldots, T(x_k)$ are linearly independent. If $x_1, \ldots, x_k$ were linearly dependent, then there would exist numbers $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_k$ not all $0$ such that $\alpha_1 x_1+\cdots+\alpha_k x_k=0$. But then it would follow that $\alpha_1 T(x_1)+\cdots+\alpha_k T(x_k)=0$, i.e., a non-trivial linear combination of vectors $T(x_1), \ldots, T(x_k)$ is zero. However this is impossible if $T(x_1), \ldots, T(x_k)$ are linearly independent. We conclude that $x_1, \ldots, x_k$ have to be linearly independent.

Comment: How can we prove this?

Comment: The implication $\alpha_1 x_1+\ldots+\alpha_k x_k=0 \Rightarrow \alpha_1 T(x_1)+\ldots+\alpha_k T(x_k)=0$ holds because of the linearity of $T$.

Comment: It appears you took the linear transformation of both sides? I see how you got the left hand side α1T(x1)+⋯+αkT(xk) through using the property of linear transformations that T(ax) = aT(x). But can we always assume that T(0) = 0?

Comment: If $T$ is linear, then one has $T(0)=T(0\cdot x)=0\cdot T(x)=0$, where $x$ is any vector, i.e., a linear map always maps $0$ to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Since $T$ is linear transform, then 
$$T(0)=T(\alpha-\alpha)=T(\alpha)-T(\alpha)=0.$$
You could try to use this property.